# Remove or revert a specific commit from a master

Tags: git

Can anyone tell me how can I remove a specific commit from master? This commit is 10 commits down. I mean 10 commits have been pushed after this commit. How many ways can we do it?

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
git revert <commit id>
```

For example

```
git revert dd61ab32
```

Comment: Does it work if the commit it between several commits?